# Estrutura de Dados - Lista Encadeada Dupla em C

Tags: c, lista

Estou fazendo uma atividade proposta por um professor, a qual pede para remover um elemento do final de uma lista encadeada dupla. Só que a função que montei para resolver o problema está travando o programa. Na resolução pensei que se fizesse semelhante a uma lista encadeada simples resolveria.

Segue o código:

```
int Remover_fim_LD (Tno_ld **inicio){

    Tno_ld *aux, *percorre;

    if(*inicio == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Lista vazia! \nRemocao impossivel\n");
        return 1;
    }

    else
    {
        percorre = *inicio;         
        while(percorre -> prox != NULL)
        {
            aux = percorre;
            percorre = percorre -> prox;                    
        }

        (percorre -> ant) -> prox = percorre -> prox;
        (percorre -> prox) -> ant = percorre -> ant;
        percorre -> prox = NULL;
        free(percorre);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Não percebi é porque não usas o `aux` (penúltimo) que é o `percorre->ant`, que por sua vez será o novo último da lista.

```
while(percorre -> prox != NULL)
{
    aux = percorre;
    percorre = percorre -> prox;                    
}

free(aux->prox); // ou free(percorre);
aux->prox = NULL;
```

Libertas o último `(aux->prox)` e pões o novo último `aux` a apontar para `NULL` no campo prox.

Answer (score 3):

Vou tentar explicar didaticamente.

Primeiro vamos tentar ficar no mesmo ponto de entendimento do código, quando você sair do while, sua variável aux estará apontando pro penúltimo elemento da sua lista(Que se tornará o último após a exclusão do último) e percorre estará armazenando o ponteiro para o último elemento.

Como você tá salvando o penúltimo elemento, basta você fazer aux->prox = NULL; e dar free em percorre, já que você quer excluir o último elemento e ele está sendo apontado por percorre, você só precisará refazer o apontamento do penultimo elemento(aux) para que aux->prox = NULL; (Tornando ele o último elemento), como percorre vai ser excluído, você não precisa refazer seus apontamentos.